# Time based apache web server load balancing

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat7

I have two Tomcat nodes behind an Apache web server reverse proxy used for load-balancing.

Is there a way for me to configure the workers such that additional hosts are added to the cluster only during certain times of the day?

Comment: Is this for some kind of auto-scaling? If you have the servers, why wouldn't you want them to be configured all the time?

Comment: Yes, I want to set up auto-scaling.  

I have many applications running on several hosts and I have more than one tomcat running on the same host.  
So   
Host H1 has 2 Tomcats serving apps T1, T2  
Host H2 has 2 Tomcats serving apps T1, T2  
Host H3 has 2 Tomcats serving apps T3, T4  
Host H4 has 2 Tomcats serving apps T3, T4  
  
Apache server load balances b/w H1 and H2 to serve T1. At certain times of the day, say, T3 has low load. I would like to know if I spin up another tomcat to serve T1 on host H3, can I add that to the cluster dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although neither `mod_jk` nor `mod_proxy_ajp` (or `mod_proxy_http`) have any specific features for high-load re-sizing (that I know of), I definitely know that `mod_jk` can be configured for a number of backend instances (Tomcat nodes) and they don't all have to be running all the time.

Take the following configuration for example:

```
worker.list=T1lb, T2lb, T3lb, T4lb

worker.T1lb.type-lb
worker.T1lb.balance_workers=h1t1, h2t1, h3t1, h4t1

worker.T2lb.type-lb
worker.T2lb.balance_workers=h1t2, h2t2, h3t2, h4t2
[etc for other combinations of TXlb]

worker.h1t1.host=host1.internal
worker.h1t1.port=1111
worker.h1t1.ping_mode=A
worker.h1t2.host=host1.internal
worker.h1t2.port=2222
worker.h1t2.ping_mode=A
worker.h1t3.host=host1.internal
worker.h1t3.port=3333
worker.h1t3.ping_mode=A
worker.h1t4.host=host1.internal
worker.h1t4.port=4444
worker.h1t4.ping_mode=A

[etc for other combinations of hXtY]
```

If you simply shut-down (or don't start) the Tomcat nodes for `h1t3` and `h1t4`, then `mod_jk` will know that they are unavailable and won't send requests to them. When you start them up, they'll start taking requests.

There is another option for this configuration. It's a little cleaner, but requires a little more work.

You have the same configuration as above, but you explicitly set the `activation` state of the nodes you usually don't keep online to `disabled`, like this:

```
worker.h1t3.host=host1.internal
worker.h1t3.port=3333
worker.h1t3.ping_mode=A
worker.h1t3.activation=S
worker.h1t4.host=host1.internal
worker.h1t4.port=4444
worker.h1t4.ping_mode=A
worker.h1t4.activation=S
```

If you want to spin-up nodes `h1t3` and `h1t4`, then you'll bring those nodes online, then change the activation state of those workers from `S` (stopped) to `A` (active). Then, `mod_jk` will start sending requests to those available nodes. When you want to take them offline, put the nodes into the `S` state (stopped) again, then stop those Tomcat instances.

Lots of this is documented in the Apache Tomcat Connectors [load balancing howto](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/common_howto/loadbalancers.html), with a full reference in the Apache Tomcat Connectors [worker reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/workers.html).